# wp get post if a custom field has value

Tags: wordpress

am using WCK plugin for Custom Post Types and Fields

Its seems nice and i have done my work fine

One of my Custom Types has a custom field for upload an mp3 file

And now i want to get all the custom posts that have value for this mp3 field.

In other situations for example get all post that have thumbnail i use

```
'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'
```

Is there any similar approach to get the custom posts that have the mp3 field set.

**UPDATE**

Searching the db i noticed that there is a child post as attachment, so maybe its not a custom field problem and maybe i need to get the post that actually have attachment

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try use `'meta_key' => 'name_your_custom_field_for_mp3'` You can see [ACF documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) about this

Comment: its not working your suggestion and i also searching the db i noticed that there is a child post as attachment, so maybe its not a custom field problem

Comment: Maybe its help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/get-all-post-attachments-except-featured-image